# How to make a toggle onclick to hide and show video player's UI?

Tags: javascript

I want to show and hide the video player's elements `details`, `play_pause_button` and `controls_bar` when the video player itself is clicked but not when its elements are clicked. I have made some progress but the video player's elements hide when I click on the elements which shouldn't happen. So how can I detect that the video player was clicked but not the video player's elements.

`index.html:`

```js
var play_pause_button = document.getElementById("play_pause_button");
play_pause_button.style.visibility = "hidden";
var details = document.getElementById("details");
details.style.visibility = "hidden";
var controls_bar = document.getElementById("player_controller_bar");
controls_bar.style.visibility = "hidden";

document.getElementById("video_player_box").onclick = function () {
    if (controls_bar.style.visibility == "hidden") {
        play_pause_button.style.visibility = "visible";
        details.style.visibility = "visible";
        controls_bar.style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        play_pause_button.style.visibility = "hidden";
        details.style.visibility = "hidden";
        controls_bar.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#video_player_box {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(22,22,23);
}
#video_player_box video {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    pointer-events: none;
}
#video_player_box img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
#video_player_box #details {
    width: 100%;
    height: 12.5%;
    background-color: rgb(108, 171, 247);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
#video_player_box #play_pause_button {
    background-color: rgb(108, 171, 247);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#video_player_box #play_pause_button img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -25% 0px 0px -25%;
}
#video_player_box #player_controller_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(108, 171, 247);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.controller_bar_block1, .controller_bar_block3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
.controller_bar_block2 {
    flex: 7;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}
#video_player_box #seek_bar {
    padding-top: 3px;
    background: rgb(108, 171, 247);
    border: rgb(22, 22, 23) 1px solid;
    border-radius: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    height: 4px;
    flex: 7;
}
#video_player_box #seek_bar::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
     background: rgb(22, 22, 23);
     height: 1px;
     width: 1px;
     cursor: pointer;
     border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video_player_box">
        <div id="details"></div>
        <div id="play_pause_button">
            <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/31/31128.png">
        </div>
        <video poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c5/Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg/220px-Big_buck_bunny_poster_big.jpg" src="https://dash.akamaized.net/akamai/bbb/bbb_640x360_60fps_1200k.mp4"></video>
        <div id="player_controller_bar">
            <div class="controller_bar_block1">00:00:00</div>
            <div class="controller_bar_block2">
                <input id="seek_bar" type="range" min="0" value="0" max="634">
            </div>
            <div class="controller_bar_block3">00:10:34</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the event's `target` property. The target property references the element that was actually clicked, even when you attach the handler on a ascending element

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

you will receive the reference to the event as the first argument of your onClick handler

```
myElement.onclick = function (ev) {
    if (ev.target.id === 'details') { 
        // the clicked element is the details element
    }
}
```

you can also check if the target is the video element for example.

```
console.log(ev.target.nodeName === 'VIDEO')
```